# What Apache Commons email server works on localhost?

Tags: java, apache, localhost

I am trying to send emails from a development computer running Tomcat on Apache. I am developing on Windows but others are developing on Macintosh or Linux. I have not been able to determine which host and port to use. I do not know where the password came from.

```
public void sendPackage(String toEmailAddress, String subject, String content)
{
    Url url = ((WebRequest)RequestCycle.get().getRequest()).getUrl();
    String fullUrl = RequestCycle.get().getUrlRenderer().renderFullUrl(url);
    if (fullUrl.toLowerCase().contains("localhost"))
    {
        sHost = "localhost";    //"smtpout.secureserver.net";
        iPort = 465;    //25;   //9090; 
        sFrom = "info@mywebsite.com";
    }
    else
    {
        sHost = "mail.mywebsite.com";
        iPort = 587;
        sFrom = "mail@mywebsite.com";
    }

    try
    {
        Email email = new SimpleEmail();
        email.setDebug(true);
        email.setHostName(sHost);
        email.setSmtpPort(iPort);
        email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator(sFrom, "tuscul312"));
        email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
        email.setFrom(sFrom);
        email.setSubject(subject);
        email.setMsg(content);
        email.addTo(toEmailAddress);
        email.send();
    }
    catch (EmailException eex)
    {
        logger.error("sendPackage failed: " + eex);
        eex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The stack trace showed

```
[ERROR] 2018-05-11 17:50:37.096 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] SendEmail - sendPackage failed: org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : localhost:465
org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : localhost:465
```

and

```
Caused by: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 465; timeout 60000;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2118)
```

Should this hard-coded configuration work?
Are there server settings somewhere else?

Comment: While Windows may not have a local SMTP server, a Unix based O/S will still need an SMTP relay.  You can't just send from anywhere to anywhere anymore - the days of open SMTP relays are long gone.  You could, however, use Gmail - see [the settings page](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I have just added a bypass for localhost and will try to determine what configuration settings are required for the server.